# How to use SonarLint connected mode for custom rules in Spring Tool Suite (IDE)?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

I have a SonarQube server up and running which has custom rules configured which needs to be reflected in SonarLint. I have run a SonarQube scan, and the projects are being shown in https://localhost:9000 UI screen.

lets come to the SonarLint. Without binding the project, I am getting issues as per default rules configured in SonarLint.

But when I bind the module with the SonarQube project, issues are not showing up. Its not even single violation in any one of class.

Answer (score 1):

You're not getting this to work because it doesn't exist yet in SonarLint.

"Soon" tho...

Comment: does this feature in sonar lint not supported in any IDE?.If so can you list out those IDEs.

Comment: There's SonarQube plugin for JetBrains IDEs: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7238 It worked on first try for me, but not ever since :(